# saving entire file in VIM

Tags: windows, vim

I have a very large CSV file, over 2.5GB, that, when importing into SQL Server 2005, gives an error message "`Column delimiter not found`" on a specific line (82,449).

The issue is with double quotes within the text for that column, in this instance, it's a note field that someone wrote "`Transferred money to ""MIKE"", Thnks`".

Because the file is so large, I can't open it up in Notepad++ and make the change, which brought me to find VIM.

I am very new to VIM and I reviewed the tutorial document which taught me how to change the file using `82,449 G` to find the line, `l` over to the spot, `x` the double quotes.

When I save the file using `:saveas c:\Test VIM\Test.csv`, it seems to be a portion of the file. The original file is 2.6GB and the new saved one is 1.1GB. The original file has 9,389,222 rows and the new saved one has 3,751,878. I tried using the `G` command to get to the bottom of the file before saving, which increased the size quite a bit, but still didn't save the whole file; Before using `G`, the file was only 230 MB.

Any ideas as to why I'm not saving the entire file?

Answer (score 4):

You really need to use a "stream editor", something similar to `sed` on Linux, that lets you pipe your text through it, without trying to keep the entire file in memory. In sed I'd do something like:

```
sed 's/""MIKE""/"MIKE"/' < source_file_to_read > cleaned_file_to_write
```

There is a [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

As a second choice, you could use a programming language like Perl, Python or Ruby, to process the text line by line from a file, writing as it searches for the doubled-quotes, then changing the line in question, and continuing to write until the file has been completely processed.

VIM might be able to load the file, if your machine has enough free RAM, but it'll be a slow process. If it does, you can search from direct mode using:

```
:/""MIKE""/
```

and manually remove a doubled-quote, or have VIM make the change automatically using:

```
:%s/""MIKE""/"MIKE"/g
```

In either case, write, then close, the file using:

```
:wq
```

In VIM, direct mode is the normal state of the editor, and you can get to it using your <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I think I'm a little confused as to your answer. VIM opened the file with no issues. I went to the specific line in question and changed the ""MIKE"" to MIKE. When I saved the file (using both methods, :saveas and :wq) it's only a portion of the original.
Is there a way to make it open the whole thing?

The issue with piping through the text is that I don't know where all the issues are until SQL Server tells me there's a problem at line X. I then go look at line X, fix the problem and move on. This time it was ""MIKE"" next time it could be anything.

Comment: I can tell you're on Windows, but which version of the OS? Also, see the link for [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can also split the file into smaller more manageable chunks, and then combine it back. Here's a script in bash that can split the file into equal parts:

```
#!/bin/bash

fspec=the_big_file.csv
num_files=10 # how many mini-files you want

total_lines=$(cat ${fspec} | wc -l)
((lines_per_file = (total_lines+num_files-1) / num_files))
split --lines=${lines_per_file} ${fspec} part.
echo "Total Lines = ${total_lines}"
echo "Lines per file = ${lines_per_file}"
wc -l part.*
```

I just tested it on a 1GB file with 61151570 lines, and each resulting file was almost 100 MB

Edit:

I just realized you are on Windows, so the above may not apply. You can use a utility like [simple text splitter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simpletextsplit/) a Windows program which does the same thing.

Comment: That sounds like a good option, thanks! I've never used bash before. I'm running windows 7, 64 bit, is there something I can download to run this with?

Comment: If bash is available, so should `split`, which will "`split a file into pieces`" and is the essential part of breaking the file into chunks. After editing, use `cat` to put them back together.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to this... split is a command in VIM or bash? If it is in VIM, wouldn't I need to load the whole file, which is part of the issue?

Comment: Split is a command in Bash. You could use something reasonably lightweight like [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow) to run these commands on Windows 7.

Comment: Split isn't a command in Bash, it's a separate app available at the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

When you're able to open the file without errors like `E342: Out of memory!`, you should be able to save the complete file, too. There should at least be an error on `:w`, a partial save without error is a severe loss of data, and should be reported as a bug, either on the vim_dev mailing list or at http://code.google.com/p/vim/issues/list

Which exact version of Vim are you using? Using GVIM 7.3.600 (32-bit) on Windows 7/x64, I wasn't able to open a 1.9 GB file without *out of memory*. I was able to successfully open, edit, and save (fully!) a 3.9 GB file with the 64-bit version 7.3.000 from [here](http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/). If you're not using that native 64-bit version yet, give it a try.